# Выполнить SQL запрос с вычисляемыми значениями

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Нужно выполнить запрос, используя Entity Framework Core:

```
SELECT to_seconds(now()) - to_seconds(lastaccess) as seconds 
FROM survey WHERE id=@param
```

Такой код не работает:

```
var i = _db.Database.FromSql<int>(
    @"SELECT to_seconds(now()) - to_seconds(lastaccess) as seconds 
      FROM survey WHERE id=@param;", 
    @param).ToList();
```

Пишет, что 'DatabaseFacade" не содержит определение для "FromSql"

Пыталась включить это поле в сущность, сделав его NotMapped:

```
entity.Property(e =>e.LastAccessComputed)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("to_seconds(now()) - to_seconds(lastaccess)");
```

В этом случае ругается база, т.к. она ищет поле в таблице.

Как получить результат такого запроса?

Comment: Раз одна запись не проще ли вытащить ее и получить период через DateTime?

Comment: У меня на сервере другое время, к тому же подобных вычислений с использованием псевдонимов очень много в будущем предстоит сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в версии.
In EF Core 1.0, one way to do that is write ADO.NET code and get the database connection from EF.

```
var conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    try
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string query = "SELECT EnrollmentDate, COUNT(*) AS StudentCount "
                + "FROM Person "
                + "WHERE Discriminator = 'Student' "
                + "GROUP BY EnrollmentDate";
            command.CommandText = query;
            DbDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var row = new EnrollmentDateGroup { EnrollmentDate = reader.GetDateTime(0), StudentCount = reader.GetInt32(1) };
                    groups.Add(row);
                }
            }
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```